# Display results of dynamic SQL stored in a table SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, dynamic-sql

I have a table that's being used by and application to set some variables over there.
However one of the things that it does is creating files, and the file names and directories are saved in the tables.
but i want the file name to be an expression like `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),20) + '.txt'` so I'd like to have this saved in the table as a SQL Expression and then evaluate it to get the value `2012-03-27.txt` out of it.

Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

Dynamic SQL SP might work but it'll be way complicated, is there any other way?

**Addition**

A computed column won't work because i want different expressions on each row.

if there would such a thing that i can have a computed column where i can enter a different value in each line would be awesome!

Comment: You're not going to be able to evaluate T-SQL expressions inside of T-SQL without nesting and dynamic SQL, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved!

In my perticular case the "Application" is an SSIS package, so what i did is very simple,

1. I grab the value from the table into a variable `@User::srcFile`
2. I make an execute SQL task, setting the sql statement expression to `"SELECT " +  @[User::srcFile] + " AS FileName"`
3. At the result set section i assigned the `FileName` to `User::srcFile`

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in as a computed column in the table definition with the expression for the column having exactly the code you supplied, and you should be all set!

Answer (score 0):

Well, not likely to be incredibly efficient, but here's one way:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(sql NVARCHAR(2000));

INSERT @x(sql) VALUES
  ('CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),20) + ''.txt'''),
  ('CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) + ''.sql''');


DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += ' UNION ALL SELECT ' + sql FROM @x;

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 11, '');

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Results:

```
2013-02-27.txt
20130227.sql
```

Comment: so what if i want the row id in the result set?

Comment: @Eli could you post a complete question please, with all of your requirements? Not interested in playing hunt and peck all day.